# Question about the conditional expectation $E[Y^2|X]$ where $Y=E[X|\mathscr{G}]$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, analysis, conditional-expectation

I am confused with the meaning of $E[Y^2|X]$ for which $E[Y|X]$ exists.
When there is a density for $E[Y|X=x]$ I know that it would simply be $E[Y^2|X=x] = \int y^2 p_{Y|X=x}dy$.

But what about the general case where $Y$ is the random variable that satisfies $Y=E[X|\mathscr{G}]$ is $\mathscr{G}$ measurable and we have the partial averaging property $$\int_A Y dP = \int_A E[Y|X] dP = \int_A X dP$$ for all $A\in \mathscr{G}$?

To sum it up, I am wondering how to interpret $E[Y^2|X]$ if $E[Y|X]$ exists in the standard form but without a density and its relation to $E[Y|X]$.

Comment: Roughly speaking, you can define $F(t)=P(Y\leq t|X=x)$ to be the conditional CDF of $Y$, and then say that $E[Y^2|X=x]=\int t^2 dF(t)$.

Comment: @Brian But that's similiar to the case with pdf's. I am wondering about general (not restricted to real) cases.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is $E[Y|X]$ or $E[Y^2|X]$. In general, conditional expectation can be interpreted as the best guess you can make from the information (=$\sigma$-algebra) you are conditioning on. In the $E[Y|X]$ case, it is about the best guess of $Y$ from the information from $\sigma(X)$, which you can interpret as the distribution of $X$. By the way, if $E[Y^2|X]$ exists, then $E[Y|X]$ always exists, given that $X$ and $Y$ are both measurable in terms of larger $\sigma$-algebra.